# 2 AP (TP-LINK) - bridge mode - security issues

Tags: wifi, wpa2

I connect two TP-LINK APs (TL-WA901ND) together over bridge-mode. It's all working fine but there is no option to set up some wifi-security (WPA/WPA2).

Do I need wifi-security over bridge-mode?
Any ideas, tips or tutorials are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Please check for a "bridge password" somewhere (after, of course, updating your firmware) - there's some reference to one in [a Whirlpool forum post](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1610951), though another user in that post couldn't find it.

As far as needing security, unless you want other to be able to intercept your data and see what you're doing or possibly inject themselves into your network, I would very much recommend some sort of security over bridge mode.

If there is no "bridge password", then I'd recommend one of three things:

1) Upgrade to something different, like a [Ubiquiti](http://www.ubnt.com/), that does allow for WPA2 in bridge mode (an example with screenshots is in [this tutorial](http://blog.gowifi.co.nz/2013/07/ubiquiti-point-to-point-wds-bridge.html), backed up by the [Ubiquiti AirOS 5.5 manual](https://www.streakwave.com/ubiquiti/resources/airOS_UG_V55_3-20-12.pdf%E2%80%8E) which calls out only AP-Repeater Auto mode as not allowing WPA/WPA2 "because WPA or WPA2 requires different roles on AP
configuration (authenticator or supplicant).").

2) Set up your network so the only traffic over the wireless bridge is tunnelled through a VPN.  Personally, I like [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html) with certificate based authentication, which [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) makes very easy, but properly configured IPSec also works, as do many (but not all) other VPN solutions.

3) Both of the above - WPA2 protected WiFi carrying a VPN tunnel.  This means that, very likely, both would have to be broken in order for your data to be read (i.e. if, long ago, an attacker captured the Wifi traffic of someone using brand-new WEP in 1999 carrying a secure VPN [say, 3-key TripleDES], even today, while the WEP encryption would have been long broken, the secure VPN is likely to still be secure).